# can we create an artificial cloud by evaporating ground water?

Tags: evaporation

I need a clarity about whether an artificial cloud can be made by human or not,if it is so, then it will be useful for many.

Comment: How would it be useful? For irrigation? More conventional methods of transporting water are bound to be more reliable, and cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Artificial clouds (in the form of vapor trails) have been made by humans for as long as aircraft have been capable of high-altitude flight. It is not clear whether such clouds can be put to any useful purpose, although in the 1950's the US Air Force investigated their use as a way of upsetting the weather patterns in countries hostile to US interests.